# SQL/php - Stored procedures - One procedure bugs the rest of my code!

Tags: php, mysql

SQL version - 5.0.77 
Using PHPMyAdmin

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkStudent (IN email VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT email, name, gender, dob, status
FROM studentCOMP
WHERE studentCOMP.email = email;

END$$
```

PHP code:

```
//$exist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentCOMP WHERE (email ='$email')");
$exist = mysql_query("CALL checkStudent('$email')");
$rowresult = mysql_num_rows($exist);    

if($rowresult == 0)  //if 0 results are returned from the earlier query
{
    echo "Please enter a valid email address- Student does not exist";
} 
else
{
    $exams = mysql_query("
        SELECT StudentExamLink.examID, examCOMP.date, examCOMP.medallevel, examCOMP.mark, examCOMP.dancestyle 
        FROM StudentExamLink 
            INNER JOIN examCOMP 
                ON StudentExamLink.examID=examCOMP.examID 
        WHERE (StudentExamLink.email ='$email')
    ");
    $rowresult2 = mysql_num_rows($exams);
    echo "$rowresult2 number of rows";
}

if ($rowresult2 == 0)
{
    echo "no exams taken";
}
```

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help with my problem. When I run the code above with

```
$exist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentCOMP WHERE (email ='$email')");
```

replacing the stored procedure everything works fine. But when I substitute in the Stored Procedure, it causes the piece of code

```
$exams = mysql_query("
    SELECT StudentExamLink.examID, examCOMP.date, examCOMP.medallevel, examCOMP.mark, examCOMP.dancestyle 
    FROM StudentExamLink 
        INNER JOIN examCOMP 
            ON StudentExamLink.examID=examCOMP.examID WHERE (StudentExamLink.email ='$email')
");
```

to return no rows, even though it should return some. Is the stored procedure locking up the table or something? Im not sure how to fix it, When ever I do it on other pages it also messes up subsequent queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some error checking would probably help in figuring out what's going on. Do you get an error printed if you add `if (!$exams) echo mysql_error();` after that second `mysql_query()`? What if you do similar for the first?

Comment: `mysql_query("CALL checkStudent('$email')");` You are opening yourself to a world of hurt with this line. This query is opened to SQL injection.

Comment: Matt-when i put it after the first mysql query i get 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'

Comment: and after the second I get nothing extra

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much love from stored procedures that return result sets.

Better to create a temporary table in your stored procedure and select from that in your php code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkStudent (IN email VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY temptable 
SELECT email, name, gender, dob, status
FROM studentCOMP
WHERE studentCOMP.email = email;

END$$
```

And then

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM temptable";
$exams = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go tomorrow. So I'd have to call the checkStudent procedure just before the $query you have given?

Comment: Doing it this way now returns 0 results....I will give it another go later, but for now its not that important, I can just use the typed out query, but thank you